# Need to retrieve different records but

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve data without duplicated records ..the problem is that  the duplicated records have similar values in all columns except a specific column called seq_id so i can not use distinct ...  My select must have seq_id ...this is the code

```
SELECT x.seq_id,
       y.name,
       x.user,
       x.time_1,
       y.acc_num
FROM table1 y,
     table2 x
WHERE y.c_id=x.m_id;
```

The result looks like this

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Seq_id      |name      |user      |time     |acc_n ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 100         jim.        Ali.      10:11:30  0098   ║
║ 101         jim.        Ali.      10:11:30  0098   ║
║ 102         john        sam       04:19:30  0097   ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I want it to be like

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Seq_id |name  |user   |time      |acc_n ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 100    jim.   Ali.    10:11:30   0098   ║
║ 102    john   sam     04:19:30   0097   ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Why choose Seq_id = 100  and not 101 ?

Comment: It does not matter which one to choose ..i just want one of them

Comment: You might try using GROUP BY in the select and then include the columns that you expect to be the same. There are a few variants of using the HAVING clause to remove duplicates as well. Try googling 'sql select without duplicates'

Answer (score 5):

> "It does not matter which [seq_id] to choose ..i just want one of them"

In which case simple aggregation will solve this for you.

```
SELECT min(x.seq_id) as seq_id,
       y.name,
       x.user,
       x.time_1,
       y.acc_num
FROM table1 y,
     table2 x
WHERE y.c_id=x.m_id
group by y.name,
       x.user,
       x.time_1,
       y.acc_num;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please avoid using old join syntax. Use `INNER JOIN`instead.

Now apart for the group by as answered by APC, you can also use Analytical function to achieve the same.

```
Select * from 
 (SELECT x.seq_id,
       y.name,
       x.user,
       x.time_1,
       y.acc_num,
       Row_number() over (partition by  
       y.name, x.user, x.time_1,y.acc_num 
       order by x.seq_id) as rno 
 FROM 
  table1 y
    INNER JOIN
  table2 x 
    ON y.c_id=x.m_id
) where rno=1
```

Comment: I will try solutions ..thank you all ..happy to learn from you...

Answer (score 0):

```
select x.seq_id, y.name, x.user1, x.time_1, y.acc_num
from table20 x, table21 y
where x.seq_id = y.seq_id
and x.seq_id = (select max(x1.seq_id)
from table20 x1, table21 y1
where x1.seq_id = y1.seq_id
and y.name = y1.name 
and x.user1 =x1.user1
and x.time_1=x1.time_1
and y.acc_num=y1.acc_num)
```